# how to call any method of Project from classlibrary?

Tags: c#, .net, class-library

I have Class Library Where a class of multithreading Of Producer and consumer based.

```
private void WorkDeQueue()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string Url = null;
            lock (locker)
            {
                if (queueList.Count > 0)
                {
                    Url = queueList.Dequeue();
                    /* return if a null is found in the queue */
                    if (Url == null) return;
                }
            }
            if (Url != null)
            {
                /* if a job was found then process it */
                GetData(Url); //This Is a Method 
            }
            else
            {
                /* if a job was not found (meaning list is empty) then
                * wait till something is added to it*/
                wh.WaitOne();
            }
        }
    }
```

This GetData method has no body on that class.
How can I call any method of my project in place of GetData.

I tried with factory Pattern and also with reflection, but both didn't work for me.
So plz tell me how I can call any method of my project from here.

Comment: More code, please. Specifically, I'd need to see where & how the GetData method is declared, and if any namespaces are getting in the way.

Comment: @adam, I think that's the code of a library he can't edit and GetData isn't implemented in that library. Not really sure tough :s

Comment: @Stormenet: Aha, now it makes more sense. Not that I can figure out the answer any easier now.

Comment: Yes your right this is class library and getdata is not implemented any where.how need a solution that how can i call any method of my project insted of Getdata.

Comment: Can you show us the GetData signature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really a lot of info to go on, but I'd probably make GetData in to a delegate so you can just replace it with whatever is needed when you create the class instance.  Something like:
'
    public class Class1
    {
        public delegate void GetDataDelegate(string url);
        private event GetDataDelegate GetData;

```
    public Class1(GetDataDelegate getData)
    {
        GetData += getData;
    }

    //blah blah blah
}
```

'